# Supplying object to chart component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I'm trying to pass data to a chart component that requires data in this format:

[image: -- image here --]

With the following code I am taking data from an existing object `items` to create a new object `performanceSeries` to pass onto the chart component:

```
const performanceSeries = {
  id: "Performance",
  data: []
};

for(const { date, performance } of items)
    performanceSeries.data.push({ x: date, y: performance });
```

But, I am getting this error in Chrome console:

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop data of type object supplied
>   to Line, expected an array.

I'm confused, does the chart documentation want an object or an array or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Yup, pass `[performanceSeries]`.

Comment: Thanks @JonasWilms, that was indeed it.